# Proof verification of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{q^n}{n} = 0$ for $|q| < 1$ using $\epsilon$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

> Prove 
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{q^n}{n} = 0
> $$ for $|q| < 1$ using $\epsilon$ definition.

Using the definition of a limit:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{q^n}{n} = 0 \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \{ \forall\epsilon>0 ,\exists N\in\mathbb N, \forall n > N : \left|\frac{q^n}{n} - 0\right| < \epsilon \}
$$

Consider the following:

$$
\left|\frac{q^n}{n}\right| < \epsilon \iff \frac{|q|^n}{n} < \epsilon
$$

Redefine $|q|^n$:
$$
|q|^n = \frac{1}{(1+t)^n} \le\frac{1}{(1+nt)}
$$
Thus:
$$
\frac{|q|^n}{n} < \frac{1}{n(1+nt)} < \frac{1}{n^2t} < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon
$$

So from this we may find $N$ such that:

$$
\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon
$$

Thus the limit is $0$.

Is it a correct proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct, but there is a small problem concerning the inequality $\dfrac1{n^2t}<\dfrac1n$. This is equivalent to $nt>1$. Why would that be true? All you know about $t$ is that $t>0$. So, you should deal with the inequality $\dfrac1{nt}<\varepsilon$. That is, choose $N$ such that $\dfrac1{Nt}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: That's a nice catch, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is fine.  You should mention, that the inequality $\frac{1}{n^2t }<\frac{1}{n}$ does not hold  for all $n $, but for  almost  all  $n $.

Answer (score 1):

You have::

$\dfrac{|q|^n}{n} < \dfrac{1}{n^2t}< \dfrac{1}{nt},$  $t>0$.

Let $\epsilon$ be given.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $N$, positive interger, s.t.

$N >\dfrac{1}{t \epsilon}$.

For $n \ge N$:

$\dfrac{|q|^n}{n} <\dfrac{1}{nt} \le \dfrac{1}{Nt} <\epsilon$.